# App crashing in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift

I have developed app in XCode 6.2 using swift. It works fine in simulator. I created .ipa and install it in iPhone 6. The problem is when I try to  execute the app on iPhone 6, app gets crashed. iPhone is with osx 9.0.1. and getting following error

```
{"os_version":"iPhone OS 9.0 (13A344)","bug_type":"298","timestamp":"2016-03-30 18:55:16.16 +0530"}
{
  "crashReporterKey" : "a6e459a09c863310566aa1e9fb59932d7334e570",
  "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Thu Aug 20 13:11:12 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3248.1.3~1\/RELEASE_ARM64_T7000",
  "product" : "iPhone7,2",
  "incident" : "BE3081EC-375B-4963-8EC0-F5FD36C12317",
  "date" : "2016-03-30 18:55:16.16 +0530",
  "build" : "iPhone OS 9.0 (13A344)",
  "timeDelta" : 44,
  "memoryStatus" : {
  "compressorSize" : 33689,
  "pageSize" : 4096,
  "compressions" : 1690576,
  "memoryPages" : {
    "active" : 113511,
    "throttled" : 0,
    "fileBacked" : 64281,
    "wired" : 53468,
    "anonymous" : 99663,
    "purgeable" : 493,
    "inactive" : 43390,
    "free" : 8814,
    "speculative" : 7043
  },
```